# Ideavim - Cannot re-select with 'gv' after using ':m' move command

Tags: intellij-idea, neovim, ideavim

In my .ideavimrc I am currently trying to implement a macro that allows me to move a selected block of code multiple time using J and K.

The problem is that `gv` doesn't give me back my old selection after doing a move command with `:m`

Do you know if there is any way to use `gv` after doing a move command (`:m`) with ideavim ?

I used this command in neovim and it worked :

```lua
vim.keymap.set("v", "K", ":m '<-2<CR>gv=gv")
vim.keymap.set("v", "J", ":m '>+1<CR>gv=gv")
```

It moved the selected block of code down and then give me back the selection so I can move it again.

Now I want to translate it to vimscript but with the limitations of ideavim.
I tried few things that look approximately like this:

```
vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

But it doesn't work so I tried manually and I seems like after doing  `:m '<-2` the `gv` command doesn't give the last selection back.

Comment: What is your IdeaVim version? There was an old bug with restoring selection after moving lines, but it's already fixed in latest releases.

Comment: Yes needed to update to latest version of Android Studio to have the fixes thank you.